# POST request not behaving as intended

Tags: ajax, django

I've been trying to get my button to send a POST request to the submitted URL, which does a write back to the database.  The application looks like the POST request gets sent, but after hitting the button my URL never changes and the print at the submitted URL appears to be an empty set.

This is my jquery/ajax call for the button:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-primary my_select" type="submit">Request Access</button>
              <script>
              $(document).ready(function () {
                  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      var phi = $('#phi').val();
                      var accesslevelid = $('#accesslevelid').val();
                      $.ajax({
                          url: "{% url 'submitted' %}",
                          headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                          data: {
                              phi: phi,
                              accesslevelid: accesslevelid,
                            },
                          type: 'POST',
                          success: function (result) {
                              // do something with result
                            },
                        });
                    });
                });
              </script>
```

I'm expecting my POST of the Application List, PHI flag, and Access Level gets sent as a POST to my submitted URL.  My view for submitted is the following:

```
 def submitted(request):
    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    checkedlist = request.POST.getlist('report_id')

    coid = User.objects.filter(coid = request.user.coid).filter(formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    facilitycfo =  QvDatareducecfo.objects.filter(dr_code__exact = coid, active = 1, cfo_type = 1).values_list('cfo_ntname', flat = True)
    divisioncfo =  QvDatareducecfo.objects.filter(dr_code__exact = coid, active = 1, cfo_type = 2).values_list('cfo_ntname', flat = True)

    print (f"checkedlist prior to post:{checkedlist}")

    selectedaccesslevel = request.POST.get('accesslevelid')


    selectedphi = request.POST.get('phi')



    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in checkedlist:
            requestsave = QVFormAccessRequest(ntname = owner.formattedusername, first_name = owner.first_name, last_name = owner.last_name, coid = owner.coid, facility = owner.facility, title = owner.title
                                      ,report_id = i, accesslevel_id = selectedaccesslevel, phi = selectedphi , access_beg_date = '2017-01-01 00:00:00', access_end_date = '2017-01-31 00:00:00')
            requestsave.save()
            print (f"postlist:{checkedlist}")
            print (f"accesslevel:{selectedaccesslevel}")
            print (f"phi:{selectedphi}")


    return JsonResponse({'is_success':True})
```

My post looks like it occurs when I press my button:

[]
[12/Dec/2017 08:54:45] "POST /account/submitted/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1149

However, the URL doesn't switch to submitted.  My list for checkedlist appears to be an empty set.  When visiting submitted and having my print statements occur, i get nothing like the POST never occurred.

My form action is the following:

```
<form action = "{% url 'submitted' %}" form method = "POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
```

Comment: Yes because **that is the entire point of Ajax**. If you want the URL to change, don't use Ajax.

Comment: How can I make this work without Ajax?  Just POST to the same url?

Comment: POST to whatever URL routes to the `submitted` view. If you leave `action` blank, it will POST to the current url.

Comment: Your form is already set to post to the submitted URL. Remove the JavaScript and just let it do it.

Comment: Then the drop down select option will do nothing.  One is a Yes/No flag, the other is a description, where the post sends the id to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajax is build to do background client server operation or load part of the page dynamic to avaid heavy requests

## Example

most of social medias feeds use ajax. when you scroll the view a ajax request is send to server to retrieve the next feed .

in your case the data is posted to server successfully.  but change the URL is not available by server at this point but you can do this with a trick ...
in your `view.py` file

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in checkedlist:
            requestsave = QVFormAccessRequest(ntname = owner.formattedusername, first_name = owner.first_name, last_name = owner.last_name, coid = owner.coid, facility = owner.facility, title = owner.title
                                      ,report_id = i, accesslevel_id = selectedaccesslevel, phi = selectedphi , access_beg_date = '2017-01-01 00:00:00', access_end_date = '2017-01-31 00:00:00')
            requestsave.save()
            print (checkedlist)
            print(selectedaccesslevel)
            print(selectedphi)
        return JsonResponse({'is_sucess':True})
```

this `JsonResponse` object will send back the data ajax.

```
success: function (result) {
    if(result.is_sucess){
        document.location = 'you url to direct page at' //
      }
},
```

this job can be done using direct post to url and then redirecting to other url i. will leave this for now

Comment: This worked great to get my URL to change, but now I'm getting the following from my console.

Comment: [12/Dec/2017 12:14:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[12/Dec/2017 12:14:11] "GET /account/login HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[12/Dec/2017 12:14:11] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1723
[12/Dec/2017 12:14:13] "POST /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[12/Dec/2017 12:14:13] "GET /account/profile HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[12/Dec/2017 12:14:13] "GET /account/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15942
checkedlist prior to post:[]
[12/Dec/2017 12:14:27] "POST /account/submitted/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20
checkedlist prior to post:[]
[12/Dec/2017 12:14:27] "GET /account/submitted/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20

Comment: I'm not sure why it's showing a GET and my if request.method == 'POST' never occurs.

Comment: you have a post request . but when you do document.location ... it will send another GET request as you see in the console line 5 and 6

Comment: If I remove my if request.method = 'POST' it gives me the following error:  ValueError at /account/submitted/
The view accounts.views.submitted didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.